# Fetch price on click of a button using a formula

Tags: formula

I need to add a feature to my website that will fetch a price when a customer enters a number into the green "Miles" input box and clicks the blue "Get Price" button. On clicking this button the code will use the number entered into the input box to calculate a price using a formula. The price then needs to be displayed to the right of the blue button.

[image]

Unfortunately, the formula to work out the price is quite complicated. I know how the formula looks in excel but I have absolutely no experience in JS at all! Basically, for anything up to and including 50 miles, the price is £50, then, for every mile thereafter, 50p is added. In excel the formula looks like this:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I really do know bugger all about JS!... the only thing I've managed to figure out so far is that the code needs to go here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution (try it on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frL01ex6/)). This can be simplified but, since you're a JavaScript beginner, I tried to keep the code long and simple, rather than short and unclear.

```js
export function getprice_click (e) {
   let miles = document.getElementById("miles").value;
   let price = 0;

   if (miles <= 50) {
      price = 50;
   } else {
      let remainingMiles = miles - 50;

      price = 50;
      price += 0.5 * remainingMiles;
   }

   document.getElementById("price").value = price;
}
```

Just to be clear, next time provide more informations about you problem, post code proposals and embed your code inside the post (without using images links).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't get this to work. At first it was saying 'miles' is not defined but I think I've managed to solve this problem by putting "let miles = 0;" at the start - just below where you've put "let price = 0;". The problem now is it's saying "document" is not defined. Should I be changing something on this line?

Comment: Thanks again but I still can't get this to work... have been trying all day! I'm using wix and I've copied and pasted all of your code into the single click event for the "Get Price" button.... not sure if that's what I should be doing!... I'm also not sure how to put post an image so plz see screenshot here: https://pasteboard.co/J45qUQX.jpg

Comment: If you're using Wix, then you only need to copy the code inside the `calculatePrice` function, without the HTML markup.

Comment: Sorry but what is the HTML markup? I'm rubbish I know.... I appreciate your patience.

Comment: It's now saying 'document' is not defined on the 2 rows where the word 'document' appears (i.e. 2nd line and 2nd to last line)

Comment: Just done a google search for "document is not defined" and I came across someone saying "That is pure Javascript, you can’t use that in Wix Code that way."..... Is this the problem?

Comment: For Wix related questions contact its support, please.

Comment: Unfortunately Wix won't help unless I pay them to do the website :(